# New column for a Parse object doesn't appear in Parse application core console

Tags: parse-platform

I already have an object called `Permission` in my Parse application. It has four properties, namely: `targetObject`, `roles`, `operations` and `action` which appear fine in the Parse application core console.

Now, I added one more property called `type` to the `Permission` object.

I am able to save the object and read back the `type` property in the retrieved objects but I am not able to see the new column `type` for this new property in the Parse application core console.

What do I need to do in order to see this new column in the console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try reloading the app from the drop down list of apps or signing back in.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried clicking the refresh icon in the data explorer which didn't show the new column. I didn't try reloading the app.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure why it doesn't check for new columns. I'm not 100% sure if hitting the browser refresh button will even work. But when clients add new columns, reloading the app is the way to go.  I found that even trying to manually create a column with that name will throw an error saying "a variable already exists with that name" or something, even though it doesn't show up.  Took me a bit to figure out as well.

Answer (score 1):

As soon as you create a new column, simply refresh the webpage showing the Parse Data Explorer.. they are aware of this issue, but it is set as a low priority to correct.